# Best strategy for dynamic/external menu file for website without using PHP

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking for some advice and ideas about the best way to set up a new website I have been asked to work on.

I would like to have an external header.html and footer.html file that gets included on every page.

I cannot use PHP as the client has specifically asked not to use any PHP.

I need to be able to manipulate the header css depending on the URL of the page.

Each page needs to be accessible via an href, so I don't think I can use frames for this.

Looking for some general advice on the best way to approach this.

I have set something up with jQuery but not sure if it's the best approach and would like some opinions. Thanks,

Bruce

Answer (score 0):

Jquery and Ajax w. JSON/XML will be what you want to use.

Make a data file(XML/JSON) with your nav structure.
Use Jquery to get the data file on each page when loaded, parse and append your menu.

In your data file you can have different menus, then use jquery to add logic to select a menue type based on the page you are on.